# Spring MVC - Adding GsonHttpMessageConverter causes Null @ResponseBody objects

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, gson

I'm working on a old Spring Application which contains lots of legacy code which needs to survive. Right now I'm working on a more modern approach of API usage and I've stumbled into a problem.

I've Added GSON for converting dates of different formats and front-ends (see below). But this causes a problem at runtime, the @ResponseBody objects become empty.

It all works fine in MockMVC which hooks up the config, but at runtime in Tomcat 8, it has problems. As I've been googling this for quite a while it seems that it could be a problem due to Jackson trying to parse the JSON as well.

Any idea's how I can ensure only GSON is used for JSON requests? (My requests contain only Simple Pojo's with Date, String and Long objects), but can have some nested objects.

Some code snippets:

WebConfig:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RestLoggingInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ExtendedGsonHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

ExtendedGsonHttpMessageConverter

```
public class ExtendedGsonHttpMessageConverter extends GsonHttpMessageConverter
{
    private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[] {
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-'07:00'"
    };


    public ExtendedGsonHttpMessageConverter()
    {
        super();
        super.setGson(buildGson());
    }
    protected static Gson buildGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    private static class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
                try {
                    return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.GERMANY).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
            }
            throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                    + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this configuration there will be only 1 `HttpMessageConverter` as when you use the `configureMessageConverters` that implies that you want to use manually configured converters. Basically jackson will not be in play here.

Comment: I just found out that my problem might be caused by my logging Interceptor, it was outputting the request body, that makes the Controller unable to access the body, thanks for that infor though

Comment: Correct as you can only read the request once, you would have to copy the input stream. Also Spring already has a filterto log the request which already does this for you. Check the `AbstractRequestLoggingFIlter` and its subclasses.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this, allthough I liked the interceptor since It allowed me to log the class + method for better debugging.

I'll work with the filter for now though it should be clean enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using an interceptor which was logging the request.
Logging the request causes the requestBody to be null, so now I'll be using Springs AbstractRequestLoggingFilter as in the comments.